# Why NASM warns when I store qword directly onto stack?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, immediate-operand

In NASM, when using dwords, I can write `mov dword [rbp-16], 2147483647` instead of `mov eax, 2147483647` followed by `mov dword [rbp-16], eax`.
But with qwords, this is not the case. If I wrote `mov qword [rbp-16], 2147483648` instead of `mov rax, 2147483648` followed by `mov qword [rbp-16], rax`, it gives me this warning:

```
disass.asm:35: warning: signed dword immediate exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]
disass.asm:35: warning: dword data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]
```

Why is so?

Comment: Because `+2147483648` can't be represented as a 2's complement 32-bit integer immediate (which will be sign-extended to qword).  You can do that with  `2147483647` (`0x000000007fffffff`) though, so `mov qword [mem], 0x000000007fffffff` is fine.

Comment: There is no encoding of `mov` with a generic (ModR/M or SIB) memory destination and full 64-bit immediate source.

Comment: Not sure if any existing questions directly address the fact that a value can fit in a 32-bit immediate (which won't be extended and can thus be considered unsigned), but *not* in a 32-bit immediate that has to sign-extend to the right value in the high bits.  That's what's going on here, and is hopefully clear enough from the duplicates, but if anyone disagrees we can tidy up this question and reopen.